# Parse complex XML using XmlPullParser

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I need to parse this XML using XmlPuppParser

```xml
<lfm status="ok">
    <events xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" artist="Armin van Buuren" festivalsonly="0" page="1" perPage="50" totalPages="1" total="17">
        <event xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
            <id>3353053</id>
            <title>ULTRA Buenos Aires 2013 - Dia 2</title>
            <artists>
                <artist>Armin van Buuren</artist>
                ...
                <artist>Adrian de Bernardi</artist>
                <artist>Manu Desrets</artist>
                <headliner>Armin van Buuren</headliner>
            </artists>
            <venue>
                <id>8778836</id>
                <name>Costanera Sur</name>
                <location>
                    <city>Ciudad de Buenos Aires</city>
                    <country>Argentina</country>
                    <street>Av. Espana 2230</street>
                    <postalcode/>
                    <geo:point>
                        <geo:lat>-34.61135</geo:lat>
                        <geo:long>-58.35838</geo:long>
                    </geo:point>
                </location>
                <url>http://www.last.fm/venue/8778836+Costanera+Sur</url>
                <website/>
                <phonenumber/>
                <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/54798997.jpg</image>
                ....
                <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/54798997.jpg</image>
            </venue>
            <startDate>Sat, 23 Feb 2013 17:58:01</startDate>
            <description/>
            <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/83063099.jpg</image>
            ....
            <image size="extralarge">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/83063099.jpg</image>
            <attendance>45</attendance>
            <reviews>0</reviews>
            <tag>lastfm:event=3353053</tag>
            <url>http://www.last.fm/festival/3353053+ULTRA+Buenos+Aires+2013+-+D%C3%ADa+2</url>
            <website>http://ultrabuenosaires.com/</website>
            <tickets></tickets>
            <cancelled>0</cancelled>
            <tags>
                <tag>electronic</tag>
            </tags>
        </event>
        <event xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
            ....
        </event>
    </events>
</lfm>
```

I need to parse this information: title, artists, city, country, geo, date and description

```java
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String tag = parser.getName();
            MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag);
            if (tag.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + title);
            } else if (tag.equals("artists")) {
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag);
            } else if (tag.equals("artist")) {
                if (artists == null) {
                    artists = readArtist(parser);
                } else {
                    artists += ", " + readArtist(parser);
                }
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + artists);
            } else if (tag.equals("headliner")) {
                artists += ", " + readHeadliner(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + artists);
                parser.nextTag();
            } else if (tag.equals("venue")) {
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag);
            } else if (tag.equals("location")) {
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag);
            } else if (tag.equals("city")) {
                city = readCity(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + city);
            } else if (tag.equals("country")) {
                country = readCountry(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + country);
            } else if (tag.equals("geo:point")) {
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag);
            } else if (tag.equals("geo:lat")) {
                geoLat = readGeoLat(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + geoLat);
            } else if (tag.equals("geo:long")) {
                geoLong = readGeoLong(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + geoLong);
            } else if (tag.equals("startDate")) {
                date = readDate(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + date);
            } else if (tag.equals("description")) {
                description = readDescription(parser);
                MyLog.d(TAG, "tag == " + tag + ": " + description);
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }

        }

private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        MyLog.d(TAG, "readTitle");
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
        String name = readText(parser);
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
        return name;
    }

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException,
            XmlPullParserException {
        MyLog.d(TAG, "readText");
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }

private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {

        MyLog.d(TAG, "skip");

        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I parse all information, except date and description. I think my mistake is that after parsing the location does not find the next tag. Can you change my code or give me tutorial how to parse complex XML using XmlPullParser?

Answer (score 0):

i used this code it working well.. use this code for example..

while parsing START_TAG, when you parse  tag, take one counter variable and assign it 1 and then whenever you get  tag, at that increment it by 1.Now, while parsing  tag, just check whether  tag comes for the 1st time, if it is then parse the desired value.

```
 <spaces>
 <space>
 <name></name>
 <desc></desc>
<songs>
  <song>
    <name></name>
    <thumb></thumb>
  </song>
  <song>
    <name></name>
    <thumb></thumb>
  </song>
</songs>
</space>
</spaces>



 case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("space")) {
                    cnt=1;
                    currentSpace = new Space();
                    System.out.println("space");

                } else if (currentSpace != null) {

                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) 
                     {
                        currentSpace.setName(parser.nextText());
                        if(cnt==1)
                        {
                            // you have <name> from <space>
                        }
                        System.out.println(":::"+currentSpace.getName());
                        cnt++;
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                        if (currentSpace.getId() == null) {
                            currentSpace.setId(parser.nextText());
                        }

                    }

                }

                break;
```